# Change path when running a batch script by dragging another file onto it

Tags: path, batch-file

When you run a batch script by dragging another file onto it, the location of the file being dragged onto the batch script is used as the path.

How can I reference a file that's in the same folder as the batch script?

Comment: Is a batch script normally run as though it is in the folder that the file that is dropped on it is in?

Comment: That seems to be the way it behaves, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Windows `cmd.exe`: **`"%~dp0\otherfile"`**

Here `%0` references the batch file, `~` causes any quotation marks to be removed from the value, `dp` means "disk letter and path".

See **`for /?`** for a full list of expansions. (They unfortunately only apply to numbered command-line arguments and *for* single-letter variables. To use such expansions with environment variables like `%myfile%`, you'll have to pass them to a subroutine with `call :label`.)